# In which section can I put this question?

Tags: support

The prices of software space a lot: from 1€ on markets like Google Play to 35$ of software like DisplayFusion, RegexBuddy, PowerGrep, Evernote going to some hundreds of euro (Resharper, Ndepend) and arriving to some thousand of euro (Toad, Visual Studio Ultimate).

In economy we study that it's not only a matter of costs of research and production. The pricing of products can be regulated by the Marshallian and Walrasian model of pricing.

However my knowledge of economy are very limited and I wonder if it could be a winning choice for small companies like the one which sell DisplayFusion, RegexBuddy and so on to sell their products for very cheap prices. Especially to private customers.

Comment: Not sure where on StackExchange that you could ask that question, but I don't think it would be on-topic for Programmers.  Sounds pretty broad and would need a book or three to answer it properly.

Comment: Maybe it could be narrowed asking where is possible to find further information about the pricing models.. What do you think?

Comment: Then that would be Off-topic => recommend favorite off-site resource.

Comment: Keep in mind that you're asking a really big question.  People have spent entire careers trying to figure out the answer to what you're asking.

Comment: @GlenH7: thanks, probably you are right. [OT mode on, read only if you are a curious person] probably we can tell the same about almost every topic. On everything there is someone which spent his career on. I'm aware every answer will not be exhaustive but I think that an answer can add some information is already interesting. Are you familiar with the concept illustrated in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1859910/196210

Comment: @Revious: No.  There are many questions that are constrained to a small scope.  I haven't spent my entire career learning how to assign a variable.

Comment: see [Is a question that specifically asks for a summary of a broad topic valuable to Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234642/165773)